# Is it better to access data from an class object or from $_SESSION in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, session

I am coding a sample object-oriented chat system using `AJAX`, `SQL`, `PHP` to train myself. I am saving "sensitive" user data into a database to check for a variety of inputs and processes such as login, online status, messages sent etc.

However, when a user logs into the system I check if `$_SESSION['status']` is `true` or `false` to grant access to different locations of the website. I check the data in a separated file with a class `Login.class` and from there I could now decide whether I keep the object of `Login.class` to receive information of the user and use it, or I "kill" the object after I saved everything in `$_SESSION` variables (i.e. `$_SESSION['username']` and so on…).

Basically I am interested in what is more secure or good programming and what is not. I know that [php-login project](http://www.php-login.net) is using both ways. It's kind of telling me that both of them are ok because a lot of professionals have been implementing this code. I thought that you should stick to one method, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You say you want to write a sample oop system - is accessing `$_SESSION` oop? I doubt that. Rather than having a `Login` class I'd suggest an `Auth` class in which you put your code. Imagine if you want to switch from session to cookies in the future - do you want to look through all files and replace every instance of `$_SESSION` or just update your class?

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow! It's difficult to understand, what you're trying to ask. Is it about two concepts (the *php-login* way and a *pure session* way)? What are the aspects of security you're interested in? Doing things by yourself is most of the time not more secure that using libraries.

Also: Can you provide some code for that we can see what you've already tried?

Comment: Indeed, this is a good point. My intention when I started using `$_SESSION` was training in using it, and I have never used cookies so far. But although I know them, I didn't consider the use. However, in general is using `$_SESSION` bad practice or not? Are they lacking security issues? I want to understand why not to use them

Comment: @JosuaSchmid thanks. My question is generalized, I kind of want to understand the "behind the scenes" part. So basically just if or why they shouldn't be used. I am learning thats why I am not using libraries.

So far, The code is very complex, but I can upload it to pastebin if my comment didn't clarify!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the initialization of the actual session stuff (You already know that, with `session_start()` which should probably go in your bootstrap somewhere), you should ideally attempt to NOT use $_SESSION directly, why you ask?

Because of maintainability! Say you wanted to implement another form of session, maybe you want to use memcache instead of flat file sessions, use cookies only (I say only because PHP defaults to store your session ID in a cookie, so you are in fact already using cookies!)

Also ease of reading, and minimal chance of a typo going unnoticed and causing a bug (Maybe you have to check for admin state alot, and you mistype it `$_SESSION['is_amdin]`, now had you used OOP here (Eg. `Auth::isAdmin()`) you would have recieved a fatal error about a missing function)

If you try to keep your stuff OO and use a proper IDE, you will also recieve the added benefit of autocompletion and code hints, you can PHPDOC a function, which will be used by many IDE's to provide documentation popups as you write. An assoc array like `$_SESSION` does not have any way to define hints for editors or humans!